# Creating an ISO from a Hyper-V Machine

Tags: windows, windows-8, hyper-v, deployment, wds

I'm new to this image deployment.

I used MDT to deploy I guess what you call a liteimage to a Hyper-V Machine. From there I installed several applications, tools and profile settings.

Do I sysprep the box or how to I get the Hyper-V Machine into a bootable image that can be deployed via MDT or WDS?

Comment: you convert the virtual machine back to a physical machine and/or create the image of the vm from within the vm.

Comment: How would I do that? Can I use SYSPREP?

Comment: You could. There are a half dozen ways to create an image of a machine to deploy it.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use MDT to capture your reference VM, you should create and use a 'capture image', then boot your VM on this image and follow the process.

note your VM must be syspreped and generalized in order to capture it. So first of all, run sysprep -generalize -shutdown, then boot to your capture image.

More information here : http://www.vkernel.ro/blog/sysprep-and-capture-a-windows-image-with-mdt-2012